# Effect in title is not compatible with Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have an effect on CSS and JavaScript that makes a poster rounded in the title field of a link, in chrome looks good, but in Firefox it looks like a rectangle when should look like chrome.

What I'm trying is that the rounded edge is consistent with chrome and firefox.

Example :

```
http://i.imgur.com/ltQkAON.png
```

Source :

```css
p#vtip { 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  background-color: #666666;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 9999;
  color:white;
}

p#vtip #vtipArrow {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 5px
}

.ok {
  border:1px dotted green;
  color:green;
  padding:10px
}

.vtip2 {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  background-color: #666666;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  
  z-index: 9999;
  color:white;
  background:#312c2b;color:white;
}
            .vtip{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.dropotron/1.4.3/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>



<a href="http://www.google.com" class="vtip" title="yeah 123 yeah">test</a>
```

How I can accomplish this?

Comment: why don't you use border-radius instead of -webkit-border-radius and -moz-border-radius, it is supported by both chrome and firefox (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp).

Comment: Yep, plain `border-radius` is missing in your style.

Answer (score 0):

You should use border-radius instead of the browser specific variants. This would ensure browser compatibility not only with ff and chrome.

This for example works fine for your request:

```
 <a style="border: 1px solid #000; border-radius: 5px;">Bla bla</a>
```

Also plain border-radius is supported by firefox and chrome since a looooong time ago (see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp).

Also I think -moz-border-radius was removed in newer versions of firefox (at least I can't seem to find it any more), but can't find any official post about it.